# Sequenctial value in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have 3 select dropdown and i want scenarios like below:

1. if i select 1 in dropdown1 then other value will be 2 and 3.

dropdown1:1

dropdown2:2

dropdown3:3

[image]

2. if i select 1 in dropdown2 then other would like:

dropdown1:3

dropdown2:1

dropdown3:2

[image]

3. will be like:

dropdown1:2

dropdown2:3

dropdown3:1

[image]

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/PPJEqq?editors=101)

```
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="my-controller">
  <select class="form-control" ng-options="obj as obj.title for obj in sequence" ng-model="selectedView1"></select>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options=" obj.title for obj in sequence" ng-model="selectedView2"></select>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options=" obj.title for obj in sequence" ng-model="selectedView3"></select>
</body>
```

Please see codepen link.

Comment: What you mean by "other value will be 2 and 3."

Comment: @UtkuApaydin : its just numbers

Comment: The uqestion is not clear for me :/ which other value ?

Comment: @uktu : Updated question with screenshots

Comment: Use `ng-change` on each `<select>` to trigger a function (e.g. `ng-change="onSelectChanged(1)"`, with the parameter specifying which `select` triggered the change). In that function, implement your logic by assigning appropriate values to `$scope.selectedView1`, `$scope.selectedView2`, and `$scope.selectedView3`, depending on what needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

I added the logic of changing the other select boxes in case of choosing 1 in the first box.

Please take a look [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avLEGM?editors=101).

Using the `watch` function, you can update the other boxes when the select is changed.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedView1', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue && newValue.title === 1) {
      $scope.selectedView2 = $scope.sequence[1];
      $scope.selectedView3 = $scope.sequence[2];
    }
});
```